# how to deal with maps in BPEL

Tags: xsd, bpel

I have a map structure  for example like this :

"A" : "C:\Documents\file1.txt" 
"B"  : "C:\Documents\ProjectFiles\file2.txt" 
"E"  : "D:\Input\file3.txt" 
:
:
where A, B and E .... are identifiers and I want to get special parts of this structure to invoke different web-services with different inputs from this map

Comment: Despite your illustration of the map, I assume it is an XML document? You can use XPath expressions in an `assign` activity for that.

Comment: the problem is that I can send it from my java program to the bpel process as xml message but the problem is that it is of unspecified length depending on the scenario so how to get the file path for B for example if I used xml representation like this: <filesequence> <file> <ID>"A" </ID> <path>C:\Documents\file1.txt</path></file><file> .....</file>....</filesequence>

Comment: I found  http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/WebServices/TP_BPEL/complextype.html how to access sequence normally like an array here .. but I can't find how to dynamically get the index of a certain item in the sequence if I implemented the map like two arrays .. something like filearray.getItem(identifiers_array.indexOf("B"))

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to get familiar with [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). For instance, an expression that selects the file path for B for the sample in your comment is: `/filesequence/file[child::ID="B"]/path`. You need to put that into the `from` part of a `copy` along with the reference to your variable, something like `$input.payload/filesequence...` enhanced with the namespace of the variable will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. this is nearly what I need .. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was like what @joergl stated in the comments above : " For instance, an expression that selects the file path for B for the sample in your comment is: /filesequence/file[child::ID="B"]/path"